# Sending serial data in an interrupt

Tags: serial, interrupt, atmega328, serial-data

An ATMEGA328-P chip is used with a toggle switch attached to pin 8 and a momentary switch attached to pin 9. My objective is to send the following information over serial:

1. The status of pin 8, every second.
2. Count the number of presses of pin 9, sending the value as the counter increments

I understand that to achieve point 2 I will need to utilise interrupts, but I have become stuck in the way I am trying to use them.

I am familiar with the following code's simple style:

1. Within the loop...
2. Poll the status of the input
3. Send status over serial

Code A:

```
const int SWITCH_1 = 8;
const int READ_INTERVAL = 1000;

int val_s1 = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(SWITCH_1, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(S1, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    val_s1 = digitalRead(SWITCH_1);
    Serial.print("S1:");
    Serial.print(val_s1);
    Serial.print("\n");

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(READ_INTERVAL);
}
```

When introducing the concept of interrupts, I have tried to retain the simplistic style of code A for testing purposes. The next snipped attempts to achieve the following:

1. Attach an interrupt to pin 9 when the voltage rises
2. No need for loop function (?)
3. Within interrupt callback function...
4. Increment the counter
5. Send the counter value over serial

Code B:

```
void c1_rise();

const int COUNTER_1 = 9;
const int READ_INTERVAL = 1000;

volatile int val_c1 = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

    pinMode(COUNTER_1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(COUNTER_1, c1_rise, RISING);
}

void loop() {
}

void c1_rise() {
    val_c1 ++;
    Serial.print("C1:");
    Serial.print(val_c1);
    Serial.print("\n");
}
```

I've tried to learn where I'm going wrong, but I have become stuck and have decided to ask my questions here.

- Observation: I expect to see some data sent over serial when the button is pressed, but actually nothing observable happens.
- Problem 1: This might be because the interrupt isn't being attached at all.
- Problem 2: This might be because I misunderstand the limitations of interrupt callback functions.

While trying to solve problem 1, [Arduino documentation implies](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/) that to use the `attachInterrupt` function, parameter 1 must be an interrupt, from `digitalPinToInterrupt`, but if I use that function I receive the following error message: **error: ‘digitalPinToInterrupt’ was not declared in this scope**.

From reading up about how interrupts behave, I found problem 2: it seems that even though I have declared the integer as **volatile**, using Serial from within a callback function isn't allowed. This is the limit of my knowledge currently, I hope that someone can help me out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use Serial inside an interrupt. Transmitting Serial relies on interrupts being available, and from inside an interrupt they aren't.

All Serial communication must be done from `loop()`.

So you need to just count the switch toggles and check to see if that value has changed in your loop.

```
volatile uint32_t toggles = 0;
uint32_t old_toggles = 0;
uint32_t ts = 0;

void setup() {
    pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(0, toggle, RISING);
}

void loop() {
    if (toggles != old_toggles) {
        old_toggles = toggles;
        Serial.print("C1: ");
        Serial.println(toggles);
    }

    if (millis() - ts >= 1000) {
        ts = millis();
        Serial.print("S1: ");
        Serial.println(digitalRead(3));
    }
}

void toggle() {
    toggles++;
}
```

Comment: May I ask what parameter 0 of `attachInterrupt` should be set to? Have you set to `0` arbitrarily? I am using `9` as that is the pin the switch is attached to, but using this method still isn't triggering the callback.

Comment: I have coded that for the Uno. Pin 2 is interrupt 0. Pin 3 is interrupt 1. Select the right pins for your chosen board.

Comment: Your answer is straight to the point, thanks for making it simple for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

In essence, attachInterrupt uses a macro called `ISR` (stands for Interrupt Service Routine) to register a user provided function to handle an external interrupt event.

The issue you are encountering is that `ISR` also wraps the call to your function with special instructions to clear the global interrupt flag of your microcontroller, and  set it again after your function returns. This is a good idea, and almost always what you want, because it prevents the possibility of infinitely recursive interrupts.

However, this behaviour will prevent `Serial` from working correctly, since it relies on interrupts being enabled to do its thing.

**Solution**

Although this is the default behaviour, there is nothing stopping you from enabling interrupts again inside your `c1_rise` function, as in:

```
void c1_rise() {
    val_c1 ++;
    interrupts();
    Serial.print("C1:");
    Serial.print(val_c1);
    Serial.print("\n");
}
```

Alternatively, but perhaps more involved, you can use the `ISR` macro directly by including `avr/interrupt.h`, and use `ISR(vect, NO_BLOCK)` to override the default behaviour.

Of course, you should be careful when overriding the default behaviour --- its there for a reason!

For more details about working with interrupts, I recommend reading [this documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html).